# create unique binary lists from elements in a list

Tags: c#, list, entity-framework, linq, data-structures

I want to create unique binary lists from the elements in this list.

for example;

```
  `["Jack", "John", "Ally"] ---> ["Jack", "John"], ["Jack", "Ally"], ["John", "Ally]`


 ["Jack", "John", "Ally", "Emmy"] --->
 ["Jack", "John"], ["Jack", "Ally"], ["Jack", "Emmy"],        
 ["John", "Ally"], ["John", "Emmy"], 
 ["Ally", "Emmy"]`
```

but the same values will not repeat. then i want to save these binary lists in database.

```
`var data = new Names() {
   Name1 = "Jack",
   Name2 = "John"
};

dbContext.Names.Add(data);`
```

how can I do that?

Comment: why not `["Jack", "Ally"] in the first example?

Comment: What makes this "binary"? Did you meant to say value pairs?

Comment: @letsdoit  I forgot I added.

Comment: if your source is a variant of an IEnumerable<string> then `var names = source.SelectMany((a, b) => source.Skip(b + 1).Select(c => new Names { Name1 = a, Name2 =c } ));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can run two for loops..

```
List<string> names = new List<string> { "Jack", "John", "Ally", "Emmy" };
List<List<string>> ls = new List<List<string>>();

for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < names.Count; j++)
    {
        ls.Add(new List<string> { names[i], names[j] });
    }
}
```